# How do I keep a log file per day in log4net?

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I've inherited an application that I need to keep more than a single days of logs.
It is using `log4net` for it's logging, and I have the `log4net.config` file contents below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<log4net>
  <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="logs\connector.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

The file in the log directory never has a date in it and is always called `connector.log`. 
It's created date is from a long time ago, so I think it is simply emptying the file when it ticks over to a new day (and the timestamp of logs in that file prove that).

How would I change this so that it keeps a log file per day.

Answer (score 0):

```
<appender name="SysAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
  <param name="File" value="App_Data/" />
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
  <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date" />
  <param name="DatePattern" value="&quot;Logs_&quot;yyyyMMdd&quot;.htm&quot;" />
  <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="&lt;HR COLOR=red&gt;%n异常时间：%d [%t] &lt;BR&gt;%n异常级别：%-5p &lt;BR&gt;%n异 常 类：%c [%x] &lt;BR&gt;%n%m &lt;BR&gt;%n &lt;HR Size=1&gt;" />
    <!--<conversionPattern value="%newline %n记录时间：%date %newline %n 线程ID:[%thread] %n日志级别：  %-5level %n跟踪描述：%message%newline %n"/>-->
  </layout>
</appender>
```

needn't define log file's name